# Unable to add values to each column in a csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a `csv` which has the below content

```
AB22e,AD34f,GQ22c,BQ77b,GQ00p
```

Here it only contains headers. Now to each column, I want to add a value

So I have a dictionary where I have maintained a mapping between column names and values to add. It looks like this

```
col_map = {"AB22e": ["a", "v"], "AD34f": ["c", "w"], "GQ22c": ["p", "l"], "BQ77b": ["a", "d"], "GQ00p": ["oo", "c"]}
```

This is how I add values to columns and dump it back to the `csv`

```
import pandas as pd

columns = col_map.keys()
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

for column in columns:
    df2[column] = str(col_map[column]).encode('utf-8')

df2.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

But nothing gets added to the `csv`. My final output should look like this

```
AB22e,AD34f,GQ22c,BQ77b,GQ00p
["a", "v"],["c", "w"],["p", "l"],["a", "d"],["oo", "c"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can may be create a dataframe from the available dictionary and reindex

```
pd.DataFrame({k:[v] for k,v in col_map.items()}).reindex(df2.columns,axis=1)
```

---

```
    AB22e   AD34f   GQ22c   BQ77b    GQ00p
0  [a, v]  [c, w]  [p, l]  [a, d]  [oo, c]
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `[v]` in `{k:[v] for k,v in col_map.items()}` ?. Removing `[]` seems to give error.

Comment: ok just another question. What was I exactly doing wrong? I don't see why the csv shouldn't update. Is it the `reindex` that is needed?

Comment: right! My updated data frame still didn't show up the values. However your approach works. I will accept this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df.append(col_map, ignore_index=True).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Result:

```
   AB22e   AD34f   GQ22c   BQ77b    GQ00p
0  [a, v]  [c, w]  [p, l]  [a, d]  [oo, c]
```

Comment: this is great! However I have accepted the solution provided by any. But +1 for the answer.

Comment: Not a problem! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @anky, for the tip.